# What's paramount?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

> * in the * heyday * of * * * my * life * * * after * an * * * excellent * * * * * cut * of * * * * * meat * * * a * typical * * * example * * * * * of * * * * * my * main * * * * * concern * * * was * an * * * * * apostrophe.

Comment: Joined the [Literature Stack Exchange (Literature.SE)](https://literature.stackexchange.com/), by the way :D

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the heyday of my life

> That is, in my *prime*.

after an excellent cut of meat

> That is, a *prime* cut.

a typical example

> ... a *prime* example ...

of my main concern

> ... my *prime* concern ...

was an apostrophe.

> Not exactly -- but the prime used by mathematicians to indicate differentiation and the like ($f'$) somewhat resembles an apostrophe.

And of course

> "paramount" is another word that can be an approximate synonym of "prime".

* * * * *

> Number the words-and-asterisks from 1 upwards; the words are in the *prime* positions and the asterisks in the others.

Comment: You've got the clues absolutely correct, but the asterisks part is important. It will make sense when you see it :-)

Comment: Wow, did you just know that Grothendieck fact offhand or did you look up the number?

Comment: @LordFarquaad: It's a pretty well-known "joke" in the mathematics community. (There's a very low bar for math humor.)

Comment: @Deusovi no no no, math humor's the best! How else can you start jokes with "An infinite number of mathematicians walk into a bar..." ?

Comment: Yes, I did know offhand about the Grothendieck prime. I'm fairly well versed in mathematical humour, though.

Comment: Oh, the asterisks are obvious. I'd even thought of approximately the Right Thing before, but for reasons that may be obvious I suffered an off-by-one error when doing so. Editing the explanation into my answer. [EDITED to add:] Now done.

Comment: Yup, that's it. (Originally I was going to use words instead of asterisks, but in the end I decided it was probably better, and definitely easier, this way.) Your green checkmark is in the post.